# Error: operation must use an updateable query

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access

After making the set up of the application(developed using VS 2008 and MS Access) the installation in another system works fine. But whenever I try to change the Password or id(there is a login window which the user need to access to get into the main window) it shows an error sayin "operation must use an updateable query". Can anyOne suggest the remedy?

Thank you,
Indranil

Comment: What "password or id" are you takling about? What format is your Jet/ACE file? ACCDB or MDB? Are you using Jet user-level security (MDB) or a database password? What is your connect string? What is the offending SQL?

Comment: Simple id and password to login and view the main window...connection string is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Game.accdb"
No security level i gave..offending SQL?

Comment: Last night i tried the set up on a friend1 machine(windows7 Os) it worked there efficiently, but not in mine(Vista) neither in another friend2 machine.

Comment: Your connect string should have the username and password in it, so what you provided doesn't help. When I ask for "the offending SQL" I am asking for you to post the SQL that's causing the error. I'm assuming, of course, that you're running a SQL statement after your login in order to get the error message you're reporting.

Comment: Also, you cannot change the Jet ULS user without opening an entirely new instance of Jet. In Access, this means you have to close Access and restart it, or open an entirely new workspace. Until we see the code that's causing the problem, we're all just speculating on what you're doing. If you want help, you're going to have to provide more information.

Comment: The SQL works fine when i debug in the project, but once i make the setup and install it shows the error(in some machines) when i try to update."cmd.CommandText = "update customer set userName='" & txtNew.Text & "'""

is the query. And brother i am a novice, so to be honest most the things ur asking r flyin over my head, thats why i uploaded it online
http://www.4shared.com/file/valby5fs/GameOnTest.html

so if u could check i would appreciate. I know its not the proper way,still if you could.
User name:Silchar
Password:Silchar

Comment: I dont know exactly David but somehow i build the setup n sent it to the client...n uwont believe what "It Works PERFECT"...thanks for ur support.

Comment: Sounds like a file permissions issue. Is the file being stored in a location where all users have full read/write access to it?

Comment: how to check for that? I think something is wrong with my laptop.

Comment: The issue is in the production environment, not on your laptop. If the app is being put in a location that the user does not have write access, you could experience these kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the permissions are the same for both set-ups? You will need a minimum of read and write permissions on the folder that contains the Access file.

To check permissions, it may be possible to right-click on the file or folder and choose Properties. The Security tab will show the details.

For web applications, you need to check the permissions for IUSRS.

Comment: i put the file inside debug, Last night i tried the set up on a friend1 machine(windows7 Os) it worked there efficiently, but not in mine(Vista) neither in another friend2 machine.

Comment: Can you step through the code and post the line that it stops on and a few lines around that point?

Comment: after i create the setup and then login it works fine, but whenever i try to change the password or username the message is displayed(and that also not in every machines)

Comment: however everything works kool when i debug them in VS2008, even the updation part. I am confused.

Comment: I have added a note on checking permissions.

Answer (score 2):

1. To fix this error, you need to run your application in Administrator Privilege
2. Do the following steps to run the application in Administrator Privilege
3. Change Level From

   `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />`

   To

   `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

It is available in UAC settings, located in the Project Settings