# C# / accdb: Getting error "Operation must use an updateable query."

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

I'm writing an application in C# which connects to an MS Access database (.accdb). The application will be used by several workers and each of them will get connected to the db from time to time - to refresh their presence (refresh the sign-in time).

All other functions which connect to the same database seem to work fine but this one doesn't. I'm getting the below error for some reason and it says the problem is in the line where my `ExecuteNonQuery()` is. The command text is defined with the string *myUpdateNonquery*.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Operation must use an updateable query.
```

The function:

```
public Boolean RefreshSignIn()
{
  Boolean successful = false;
  lock(dbLock)
  {
    try
    {
      string myConnectionString = connectionType + primarydbPath;
      OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(myConnectionString);
      string myUpdateNonquery = "UPDATE AgentSignIn SET signInTime = NOW() WHERE agentName = @p1";
      using(myConnection)
      {
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myUpdateNonquery, myConnection);
        using(myCommand)
        {
          myCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Char).Value = appSettings.mynick;

          myConnection.Open();
          int updatedRows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (updatedRows>0) {successful = true;}
        }
      }
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error! Failed to keep you signed in to the database!\n\n"+ex.ToString());
    }
  }
  return successful;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: operation must use an updateable query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749674/error-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query)

Answer (score 2):

The SQL looks fine.  It seems to be a permission issue, the article below outlines how to fix this issue:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error

Comment: But other methods with the UPDATE command do work and don't give me the error. This is what makes me confused :/

Comment: Okay.  In access, crate a test row in the AgentSignIn table, then create a new Query and execute the following:

UPDATE AgentSignIn SET signInTime = NOW() WHERE agentName = 'TestRow'

If that executes it may be the line: OleDbType.Char).Value = appSettings.mynick;

The data type char will only accept 1 character (not a string) you may have to change it to:

OleDbType.VarChar).Value = appSettings.mynick;

Comment: I made the permission changes from the article under your link. It seems that it's already saving the user name properly and refreshes the sign-in time. But now I get another error in a different method (signs out other, inactive users). The error is: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not use 'xxxxxxxx.accdb'; file already in use.`

Comment: Looks like another process is accessing the database file and is locking you out.  One of the main reasons people use a different RDMS than Access (Provides better concurrency).  Did you try the test row solution?

Comment: @ValCool do users have full permissions on the folder in which the Access database resides? Access creates a lockfile (.ldb) and users need, at very least, read/write permissions.

Comment: *1.* I'm thinking about switching to SQL Server Express. Do you think it could solve the problem with the "updateable query" and this "file already in use"? *2.* I've tested that RefreshSignIn method before (right after I wrote it) and it worked fine. And yes, it also saves full user name (not just one character). All methods work OK, when there's only one user connecting to the database but when there's at least two, all those weird errors show up :/

Comment: I would definately update to SQL Server.  It will fix the "file is already in use issue" as SQL Server provides excellent concurrency compared to MS Access. 

@Remou - The article I provided explains them steps.

Comment: SQL Server requires a much higher level of maintenance and is far more complicated to set up that MS Access (Jet/ACE). Both have their places. I suspect that it is an error causing the problem, not a concurrency issue.

Comment: @Remou Concurrency will be the problem if the file is locked by another process (Could not use 'xxxxxxxx.accdb'; file already in use) as Val has described.  SQL Server does not require a much higher level of maintenance IMO, it provides more complex features than Access, however you do not need to delve into them if not needed.

Comment: How do you back up and restore an SQL Server database compared to an Access database ? :)

Comment: @Remou - To backup, right click on the database -> Tasks -> Backup
To restore, right click on the database -> Tasks -> Restore

:)

If you have the knowledge to write a C# program to connect to a database and execute SQL queries IMO you can easily find your way around SQL Server to perform basic tasks.

Comment: Certainly the person who writes the program can, but what about the very small office where it is being used? It could be the case.

Comment: @Remou you are making assumptions. Again, if a user can execute a query in Access what makes it so difficult to do the same in SQL Server? Clicking the new query button provides the same functionality.  Val has stated that he/she wrote the program and is thinking of updating to SQL Server, which in my opinion is the way forward as it will help with the "File is already in use" error he/she is currently encountering.