# Error: Operation must use an updateable query. while accessing .mdb file from web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access

I want to do CRUD operations on a .mdb file through a Web Service. The Service, works fine and does all CRUD operations on my machine(dev environment).
But when I actually host it on server, it throws `Error: Operation must use an updateable query.` error when I try to test the Service using browser or any client that consumes the application.

The .mdb file has full permissions for all users of the server as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10138493/c-sharp-accdb-getting-error-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query) and [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error)
the connection string in web service is as follows.

```
string strConnection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;Data Source=";
            strConnection += Server.MapPath(".\\App_Data\\users.mdb");// + "; user id=;password=;"; 
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM user_info";

            OleDbDataAdapter userAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(strSQL, strConnection);
            OleDbCommandBuilder userCB = new OleDbCommandBuilder(userAdapter);
```

The .mdb file is not open/closed in any other program. what am I missing here.

Based on the Stack Trace I found . I am posting here the Query Execution methods if it might help

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
            OleDbCommand logCommand = new OleDbCommand(strLogSQL_User, connection);
            logCommand.Connection.Open();
            logCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            logCommand = new OleDbCommand(strLog_User, connection);
            logCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            logCommand.Connection.Close();
            return "true";
```

Comment: IS this the complete error message? I think you have omitted an important part of the exception.

Comment: The 'exception.message' contains only this. U mean inner exception

Comment: Yes, inner exception message, Another possibility is: Has the user_info table a primary key?

Comment: No Primary key explicity set for user_info table. but how does it matter??

Comment: Check the effective permissions on the *folder* in which the .mdb file resides. The IIS service account may need write permissions on the folder as well as the .mdb file (so it can create the .ldb lock file). Note also that IIS settings might possibly be restricting write access to that folder even if the filesystem permissions allow it. (You do know that using an Access database with IIS is a **bad idea**, right?)

Comment: @Thomposon: .mdb resides in App_Data folder. The Folder permission that I view in windows explorer is allow everyone. I am not sure of what IIS permissions you are referring to. Can you please elaborate on the steps. This .mdb file is just used to store some user data that the service receives, not a huge bunch of info. Also, please let me know why is it a Bad idea. Since I saw couple of apps doing this.

Comment: @Steve: the `Exception.InnerException` is NULL.

Comment: I found Stack Trace as follows :- StackTrace: at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at MyService.UserLog(String _userID, String _version) exception.Source = Microsoft Access Database Engine

Comment: "Microsoft strongly recommends against using Access in web applications." (ref: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653753.aspx#access_database))

Comment: re: possible IIS restrictions - I threw that in there because I had a vague recollection of some IIS security settings that might apply. I've never spent any time trying to get IIS to work with an Access database because of the whole "bad idea" thing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.
The problem is with the `logCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` method. its not able to figure out the command type that I am trying to execute. 
I added this to the Command before calling the `ExecuteNonQuery()` method and it worked.

```
logCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Hope it might help save someone's day.

Thanks,