# Website works on localhost but not When uploaded to server it is giving an error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have Website which works fine on localhost but not on server when uploaded, it is giving an error as Operation must use a updatable query

Code is as follows:

```
    OleDbConnection myCon;

    string path = @Server.MapPath(".") + "/Accomdation1.mdb";
    myCon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path);

    myCon.Open();
    string f = TextBox1.Text;
    string g = TextBox5.Text;
    string d = DropDownList1.Text;
    string a = TextBox2.Text;
    string h = TextBox7.Text;
    string k = TextBox6.Text;
    string u = TextBox8.Text;
    string y = TextBox9.Text;

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Accomdation (lastname, firstname,gender,UHCLID,Dateofarrival,timeofarrival,flightno,emaildi)" + " VALUES('" + f + "', '" + g + "', '" + d + "', '" + a + "', '" + h + "', '" + k + "', '" + u + "', '" + y + "')", myCon);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
    // TextBox1.Text = e1.Message;     
    myCon.Close();
```

Comment: FYI, look into parameterized queries to protect yourself from SQL injection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170578/operation-must-use-an-updatable-query-error-3073-microsoft-access

Comment: Ya i can do it later but first this is not excuting when uploaded into server

Comment: Please any one reply i am really stuck...

Comment: Without much information, I'd say is a permissions problem on your db file, take a look at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/74/Solving-the-Operation-Must-Use-An-Updateable-Query-error

Comment: why are your variables semi obfuscated? it gets compiled no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: operation must use an updateable query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749674/error-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query)

Answer (score 0):

tyr the followings!
1. make sure you are not opening "Accomdation1.mdb" while trying to execute the above code. 
2. right click App_folder under "Accomdation1.mdb" go to properties under the securiety tab
give full permission to "NETWORK SERVICE"