# operation must use an updateable query in vb.net using myapp.exe

Tags: vb.net

I am a newbie and not also good in explaning but i will try my best I hope you understand so here it is. Im trying to create application.exe with ms access database at first it works login and searching but when i try to edit or enter another data using my application.exe this happen [**operation must use an updateable query**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A80D.jpg) but when im not using .exe app no problem show
This is the step by step That i do when executing my app. why did i include this maybe, I don't know and I'm not really sure that the cause of the problem is the way of my executing the application. By the way this is my connection string that I use

```
Public cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB_HR.accdb;Jet OLEDB:DATABASE PASSWORD=dbhr123;")
```

Step 1. I put my database the bin/debug
Then

Step 2. I add my data base [Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b7mZ.jpg)

Step 3.I go to the properties of my DB_HR.accdb by right cliking and change the Copy to output Directory to Copy if newer [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPUZF.jpg)

Step 4. I  build the windows app just like i do in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f77C.png)

Step 5.I change my app.manifest code requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"  into highestAvailable [just like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJpPp.jpg)

Step 6. I use [Setup Wizad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSHo9.jpg) to create my executable application. and I add this [Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvi39.jpg) and then I created a
shorcut for my WindowsApp1.exe just like i do in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0fFT.jpg) then drag it into user's Desktop Then in the Build menu I click the batch build to create the .exe app

But the problem is still The same **operation must use an updateable query**
Can you help me please.What  should I Do? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think most of this information is irrelevant to the actual problem, which is you are trying to update some data based on a query which the Access engine cannot use for updating. When you run this under the Debug configuration, does the debugger catch the error, and at what line?

Comment: it say System.Data.Oledb.OledbExeption (0x80004005): Operation must use an updateable query. and in the bottom at 
 System.Data.Oledb.OleDbCommand,ExecuteNonQuery() at WindowsApp1.Form1.Button4_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\HR_appP2 w password\WindowsApp1\WindowsApp1\Form1.vb:line 112

Comment: Zev Spitz I already put the picture of error

Comment: So the next step I would take is to look at the file `Form1.vb` at line 112 (you can turn on the line numbers in Visual Studio), within the `Button4_Click` sub, and see what the `CommandText` property of the `OleDbCommand` object has been set to before that line. Alternatively, I would set a breakpoint at line 112, run the code, and when the breakpoint is hit, examine the `CommandText` property. The exact SQL statement is important here -- something like `UPDATE ...`.

Comment: This is my insert code   Dim Str As String = "Insert Into LOGIN([YOUR_NAME],[PASSWORD],[DATEANDTIME]) Values (?,?,?)"

Comment: And this is my update code str = "UPDATE [APPLICANT_INFO] SET LASTNAME=?, FIRSTNAME=?, MIDDLENAME=?, NICKNAME=?,  WHERE ID=?" '

Comment: The problem is when Im executing my app into .exe this appear Operation must use an updateable query. But when Im not executing my app into .exe there is no problem

Comment: 1) Generally, further details should be edited into your question, not in comments. 2) Could there be two copies of the database file?

Comment: Nope just 1 database file. maybe the way of my process of executing my app into .exe? can you help me review it or teach me another way of executing an app with database.

Comment: 1) Whether Visual Studio is attached as a debugger or not, you are still running an `.exe` file. 2) Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2749674/111794) be the issue? Is the database in a folder which your user account can write to?

Comment: nope i already check the properties of my folder where my db is in it was full control.

Answer (score 0):

I Found a solution. Try to check your [App.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcW7T.jpg)  Solution Explorer and Open it.

[If the code look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMQdM.jpg)  then You should Add this [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtsIe.jpg) then save it.

Then try to execute your program.